# Access control for uploaded files in Yii

Tags: yii, acl

What is the best way to deal with restrictions on file access? The goal is to allow access for certain uploaded file only for its author.

I've decided to keep files in /protected/files folder, and I wonder what is the best way to return these files.

1. One of possible approaches is to create db like:
   `id, user_id, name, path`.

   So user with specific user_id can access his files through request like /resource/name.jpg (having common controller named ResourceController)
2. The second approach is to just store `id, name, path` without ResourcesController. In each other controller (which needs to access user files) create an action that will perform access control.

   ```
   function actionMessageImage()
   {
     $message_id = $_GET['message_id'];
     $model = Message::model()->find( ... check user_id for access control)

     $file = File::model()->findByPk($model->file_id)

     // then make request such as $file->get(); that performs readFile()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save user_id with image will be best in this case, with min hit to the database.